# How to set up a Laravel Livewire component to make it not loaded again when navigated

Tags: laravel, navigation, components, laravel-livewire

I have a Livewire component which is used on every page (eg. notifications in header) and it is being lazy loaded. I know it will be loaded again on page refresh or click a link which does not include "wire:navigate" attribute. But when I use "wire:navigate" on a link to go to another page, I want this component stay same without mounting and refreshing again so that no extra queries will be made to increase performance.

Is it possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place your element(s) inside a `@persist ... @endpersist` block to persist elements across page visits in Livewire like so (audioplayer is an example since you didn't post any code):

```
@persist('player')
    <audio src="{{ $episode->file }}" controls></audio>
@endpersist
```

Documentation for
[Persisting elements across page visits](https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/navigate#persisting-elements-across-page-visits)

Answer (score 0):

I hope so it'll be helpfull, number of times of try this way, I'll also prefer
To maintain Livewire component state across page transitions, use the "wire:key" directive with a unique identifier for the component. This prevents it from being remounted when navigating between pages.